# Does Ext4 stores owner and group names? Or only IDs?

Tags: permissions, users, ext4, groups, bsd

**I am wondering if Ext4 file system stores names or IDs for file ownership information?** Most probably the IDs... but that makes another question.

**Does all Ubuntu versions have standardized IDs for common usernames?** For example:

- mail:8
- www-data:33
- syslog:104
- postfix:107

What about other Linux distributions? BSDs?

**Edited to clarify:** What happens when I mount Ext4 HDD on different Linux where user IDs are different? Are permissions/ownership broken? Or Ext4 stores usernames and groupnames? What happens if particular group or user is deleted?

Comment: What did you mean by "Ext4 file system stores names or IDs"?

Comment: I mean, file and directory ownership. Owner info associated with files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has a set of standardized usernames, UIDs, groups and GIDs. These are provided by the `base-passwd` package. See [my answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180458/70524) (or `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz`) for more information on those.

As for the filesystem, it stores UIDs and GIDs. The mapping between names and IDs are done by Name Service Switch (NSS) using the `passwd` and `group` databases. Unless you have the same mappings, the same UID might show up as different usernames on different systems.

If user `a` has UID 1000 on one system and creates files belong to it, and the filesystem is mounted on another system with `b` having UID 1000, then the second system will show `b` as the owner.