# Is there any reserved usersid in linux?

Tags: ntp

I am installing ntp latest package 4.2.8p6 by following this link `http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/basicnet/ntp.html`
creating user

```
groupadd -g 87 ntp &&
useradd -c "Network Time Protocol" -d /var/lib/ntp -u 87 \
         -g ntp -s /bin/false ntp
```

in the above command i am giving '87' as userid. Is there any reserved userid to install specific packages like ntp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Ext4 stores owner and group names? Or only IDs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/734957/does-ext4-stores-owner-and-group-names-or-only-ids)

Comment: (partially - the other question asks two things, one of which is relevant here)

Comment: Anything bellow 1000 is typically reserverd, unless a sysadmin alters it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's hardcoded into the latest `ntp` (check the `README`), there's no special UID for `ntp`. On MY Ubuntu 14.04.03 (YMMV):

```
$ grep ntp /etc/passwd /etc/group
/etc/passwd:ntp:x:117:129::/home/ntp:/bin/false
/etc/group:ntp:x:129:
```

Stock `ntp` runs as `UID=117`, `GID=129` here.

`UID`s less than 1000 (see `man login.defs`) are slightly more privileged than not (see `man useradd`). And, of course, there's `root` (`UID=0`).